# Best practices for FlowFile content vs FlowFile attributes

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm just getting started with Apache NiFi and I'm curious if there are any best practices around using a attributes vs content for a FlowFile.  Currently, I have it setup to read a JSON message from a RabbitMQ queue, parse the JSON into attributes and use those attributes for downstream processing.  This works, but I feel like its leaving the content of the FlowFile largely unused after JSON parsing and I'm wondering if I'm missing something.  Alot of the processors seem more geared towards working with attributes but are there any disadvantages to primarily using attributes for processing?

In my use case, the RabbitMQ message would be an event that a new document has been made available and the flow I'm building would have branching logic based on the document type to extract data from the document via NLP processes.  Currently, I'm storing the document text as and attribute but I'm wondering if there are any size considerations to account for with attributes.  Some documents could be hundreds of pages and therefore lots of text.

Thanks!

Comment: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Nifi-Attribute-Limit/m-p/149247/highlight/true#M111773

Comment: Thanks @daggett, I just came across that myself